# How can I extend L.mapbox.legendControl?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, api, mapbox

I'm trying to override legendControl.onAdd, but I can't seem to do it early enough. I can override the other functions, since they're fired after map init, but I can't seem to change the prototype?  How should I do it?

This doesn't work:

```
L.mapbox.legendControl.__proto__.onAdd = function(map) {
    console.log('map.legendControl._onAdd');

    this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'map-legends-wrap-container');
    this._subContainer = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'map-legends wax-legends');
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(this._container);

    this._container.appendChild(this._subContainer);

    this._update();

    return this._container;
};
```

Comment: Is there an error or just a silent fail?

Comment: And also what version of leaflet are you using?

Comment: I am using bleeding edge leaflet.js (0.7).  This error was due to the fact I was overriding the function .onAdd _after_ it was run by Leaflet.js.  Doh!

Comment: If you have figured out the solution please write it up (with code) so that others might benefit from what you learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.mapbox.legendControl` is a function, not a class, so you cannot extend its prototype. The best way to do this would be to create a `L.mapbox.legendControl` instance and replace its `.onAdd` method directly.